# PHP not executing because of undefined function

Tags: php, apache

PHP isn't executing because of undefined function as appears to be in the apache error log,which is

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file() in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 24

This is the PHP code where that function lies

```
$url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/new/.rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Based on phpinfo function,simplexml is enabled on my php5.6 installation. it simply appears on the list of modules..

Any ideas ?

Comment: Restart apache once and let show the phpinfo details in screenshot

Comment: apache restarted. which area do you want me to screenshot ?

Comment: I think the simplexml module is not enabled. please run this command
`sudo apt-get install php-xml` and restart apache once and see the phpinfo you got `Simplexml support enabled`

Comment: or try `sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`

Answer (score 2):

try **phpinfo()** and see if simplexml is loaded, also you can load it with uncomment  **extension=simplexml.so** in the php.ini file.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, I thought there wasn't a php.ini file ?

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu but maybe you can find it here: **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

Comment: Or use this command to find it **php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"**

Comment: I have added that line, it didn't exist. restarted apache but still same error :/

Comment: just install package **php7.0-xml** using the Synaptic package manager or ** sudo apt-get install php-xml ** in terminal.

Comment: yea that's what I had on localhost, and I've already installed it on the server..but probably isn't compatible with PHP5 which I should run with webmin right now :/

Comment: @wadie Then try `sudo apt-get install php5-xml`

Comment: Unable to locate package php5-xml

Comment: try `apt-cache search php | grep xml`

Comment: @wadie try `sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`

Comment: yep found it,working good..but prompting another error `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 1 in`